# What is the use of '\f' character.where is to use it?

Tags: java

```java
public class Task2 {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    System.out.println("UOK, \f BSc in MIT");   
    System.out.println("Whatever you are, \f be a good one.");
  }
}
```

In the above code, `\f` is used, but output only shows a `?` character inside a square.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html ... do you want to know what a "formfeed" is? Do research on that.

Comment: @Siguza it can be misleading to show a table of C escape characters to a person learning Java. For example, C has `\v`, while Java doesn't.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou My bad, I was looking at possible dupes at the same time and came to believe this was about C.

Comment: you had an unsupported character in your code instead of " (double quote)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a bunch of so-called escaped characters - characters that have some special meaning and are formed from a backslash and another character. The most common one is newline `\n`, but there are [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Many of them became less and less useful over time, such as `\f`. This is called form feed, is used to indicate to a printer that it should start a new page. You may notice multiple escape characters used to control printers, since back in the day printers were ascii controlled.

Comment: Try to use reverse video in a linux console .... or moving the insertion point for text.  ncurses uses control characters to tell the device what to do (if the device is the linux virtual console or a real heavy weigth vt100 doesnt really matter.)